# Why is ES6 treating this as a NaN?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm using React and Redux to try to increase the value of a prop everytime a button is clicked. However the prop is being treated as a NaN for some reason.

This is my reducer:

```
export default function(){
  return 0;
}
```

And the other reducer:

```
export default function (state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'VALUE_INCREMENTED':
            return action.payload;
            break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

This is my action:

```
export const incrementValue = (val) =>{
  console.log("You incrementend the value to: ", val+1);
  return {
    type: 'VALUE_INCREMENTED',
    payload: val+1
  }
};
```

And this is is the container:

```
class Thermo extends Component{
  getValue(){
    return this.props.val;
  }


  render(){
    return(
          <div>
              <Thermometer
                      min={0}
                      max={90}
                      width={10}
                      height={230}
                      backgroundColor={'gray'}
                      fillColor={'pink'}
                      current={this.props.val}
              />
              <input type = "submit" onClick={() => this.props.incrementValue(this.props.val)}value="+"/>
          </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    val: state.val
  };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({incrementValue: incrementValue}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Thermo);
```

Comment: I don't know React, but most likely `this.props.val` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Gothdo I shoul've pasted the whole container code. I'm about to edit that.

Comment: Please post your reducer code also that will be super helpful

Comment: @finalfreq please check the edit

Answer (score 1):

Here you are setting initial state to null;

```
export default function (state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'VALUE_INCREMENTED':
            return action.payload;
            break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

if you change your reducer to the following you will then have a default state object with a key for val and value of 0. Then when you map state to props it will get the correct value and not undefined.

```
var initialState = {
  val: 0
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'VALUE_INCREMENTED':
            return {...state, val: action.payload};
            break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an initial state in your reducer e.g.

```
export default function(state=0){
  return state;
}
```